# Do we have abstract equality check in ember handlebar?

Tags: ember.js

In ember handlebar, we are allowed to use the strict helper

```
eq  if (a === b)  or {{if (eq a b)}}    

ex:  1 === '1'     false
```

I need to check the abstract equality which is

```
1 == '1'      true
```

How can i achieve that in .hbs file ? with helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own helper. Twiddle for [sample helper](https://ember-twiddle.com/267326eb57c48c9f08e07b0dbca4d33c?openFiles=helpers.abs-eq.js%2C)